# IOS 9 beta 5 : CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL is return nil only password protected pdf file

Tags: iphone, xcode, pdf, ios9

I'm using following line to create a PDF reference:

**********CGPDFDocumentRef thePDFDocRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(theURL);**********

thePDFDocRef return NULL but while load without password protected file works proper ios 9 beta 5 also.

Only the problem is ios 9 beta 5 but it works proper for ios 9 beta 4 and below versions like ios 8,7,6 etc...

```
 CGPDFDocumentRef CGPDFDocumentCreateX(CFURLRef theURL, NSString *password)
{
CGPDFDocumentRef thePDFDocRef = NULL;

if (theURL != NULL) // Check for non-NULL CFURLRef
{
    thePDFDocRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(theURL);

    if (thePDFDocRef != NULL) // Check for non-NULL CGPDFDocRef
    {
        if (CGPDFDocumentIsEncrypted(thePDFDocRef) == TRUE) // Encrypted
        {
            // Try a blank password first, per Apple's Quartz PDF example

            if (CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword(thePDFDocRef, "") == FALSE)
            {
                // Nope, now let's try the provided password to unlock the PDF

                if ((password != nil) && ([password length] > 0)) // Not blank?
                {
                    char text[128]; // char array buffer for the string conversion

                    [password getCString:text maxLength:126 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                    if (CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword(thePDFDocRef, text) == FALSE) // Log failure
                    {
                        #ifdef DEBUG
                            NSLog(@"CGPDFDocumentCreateX: Unable to unlock [%@] with", theURL);
                        #endif
                    }
                }
            }

            if (CGPDFDocumentIsUnlocked(thePDFDocRef) == FALSE) // Cleanup unlock failure
            {
                CGPDFDocumentRelease(thePDFDocRef), thePDFDocRef = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
}
else // Log an error diagnostic
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"CGPDFDocumentCreateX: theURL == NULL");
    #endif
}

return thePDFDocRef;
```

}

Comment: people already have made noises at [Radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) about that, so fingers crossed it will be fixed soon by Apple; that is an iOS9b5 bug.

Comment: How can I add noise there?

Answer (score 2):

I also found same issue in iOS 9 Beta 5.
Preview do not ask for password or open protected PDF.

Same behaviour in iOS Mail application also.
STEP : Attach pdf to mail and try to open...

Must be iOS 9 Beta 5 bug...

Comment: Xcode 7 GM still have the same problem. Any work around?

Comment: Have you find any solution.because i have same problem when i load "https" url, it's work perfect when load "http" url.